# trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/inspect', which is also in package libboost1.53-tools-dev 1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8

Tags: dpkg

This is the output after `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libboost1.49-dev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
21 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,182 kB of archives.
After this operation, 24.6 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 580974 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libboost1.49-dev 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 (using .../libboost1.49-dev_1.49.0-4_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libboost1.49-dev ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.49-dev_1.49.0-4_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/inspect', which is also in package libboost1.53-tools-dev 1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.49-dev_1.49.0-4_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following commands on terminal,

```
sudo dpkg -P libboost1.53-tools-dev
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I have run sudo apt-get -f install and still have same error

Comment: Post the output of 'sudo apt-get -f install'

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-chrono1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-date-time1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-filesystem1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed
 libboost-graph-parallel1.49-dev : Depends: libboost1.49-dev (= 1.49.0-4) but 1.49.0-3.2ubuntu1 is installed

 
`

Comment: try `sudo aptitude -f install`.

Comment: I am not able to paste all the code but here is something more that keeps appearing:  `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  collada-dom-dev collada-dom2.4-dp-base collada-dom2.4-dp-dev freeglut3-dev g++-4.7 hddtemp html2text libassimp-dev libassimp3 libcf0 libcolumbus0-0
  libcolumbus0-0-common libcppunit-1.12-1 libcppunit-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libdns95 libeigen3-dev libfltk1.1 libfltk1.1-dev libfreeimage-dev`

Comment: post the output in pastebin.com and then provide the link here.

Comment: Also I have ros installed and these appears also: `ros-groovy-bullet ros-groovy-camera-calibration ros-groovy-camera-calibration-parsers ros-groovy-common-msgs ros-groovy-common-rosdeps
  ros-groovy-convex-decomposition ros-groovy-diagnostic-common-diagnostics ros-groovy-eigen-conversions ros-groovy-gencpp ros-groovy-genlisp
  ros-groovy-geometry ros-groovy-image-geometry ros-groovy-ivcon ros-groovy-kdl-conversions ros-groovy-laser-geometry ros-groovy-message-filters`

Comment: [Here it is](http://pastebin.com/ncE7C5Ux)

Comment: likewise post the output of `sudo apt-get -f install` after running `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: I have the same output

Comment: edit your question and then post the output of `sudo apt-get -f install`.That's all.

Comment: @ Avinash Raj I just pasted the result, I have been with this problem for weeks. The problem was when I updated to ubuntu 13.10. Here is the code:http://pastebin.com/3XsHYyMc

Comment: i had updated my answer.

Comment: still not working:`sudo dpkg -P libboost1.53-tools-dev
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libboost1.53-tools-dev:
 libboost-tools-dev depends on libboost1.53-tools-dev.

dpkg: error processing libboost1.53-tools-dev (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libboost1.53-tools-dev
`

Comment: try this `sudo dpkg -P --force-all libboost1.53-tools-dev`

Comment: Here is re result:`sudo dpkg -P --force-all libboost1.53-tools-dev
dpkg: libboost1.53-tools-dev: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 libboost-tools-dev depends on libboost1.53-tools-dev.

(Reading database ... 580973 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libboost1.53-tools-dev ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...`Then here is the result of`sudo apt-get -f install`http://pastebin.com/TW7xpBB9

Comment: remove `/var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.53-tools-dev_1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8_i386.deb` file by running `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.53-tools-dev_1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8_i386.deb` and `sudo apt-get install -f`.Make a copy of that file before running this command.

Comment: Here is the result: http://pastebin.com/YaZpZHFn

Comment: did you remove this `/var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.53-tools-dev_1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8_i386.deb`?

Comment: Yes I did remove that file.

Comment: try this `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.53-tools-dev_1.53.0-6+exp3ubuntu8_i386.deb`

Comment: autoremove is not necessary...